# Would it be good idea to add body {line-height:0} to get more control over all elements?

Tags: css, xhtml

Would it be good idea to add `body {line-height:0}` to get more control over elements?

For better cross browser consistency. I can add specific line-height to any element, as needed.

> body {line-height:0}
>
> p {line-height:1}
>
> h1 {line-height:2}

or body `{line-height:1}` is a better idea?

My purpose is to reset the `line-height` of all elements to `0` or none than add `line-height` later to elements as needed.

Currently computed line heights create problems.

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/maxdesign/line-height

Answer (score 3):

no, it's not a good idea.  First it's not the way people usually do it and so will be confusing, and second it's brittle -- you're liable to forget, either now or in the future.  But messing with line height will then mess with the way blocks are laid out, and have all sorts of propogated problems.

It *is* a good idea to "clean up" the CSS to a known state using a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) file.

Comment: OK than how to reset the line-height for all element?

Comment: @Alexander Taran - html5boilerplate.com's reset don't use `line-height` in his reset. Is it better way?

Comment: he used http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/ this reset and for some reason ommited body {
    line-height:1;
}

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `line-height: 1` because then you may not need to set a line height for every other element.  If you use 0 instead, you've just forced yourself to specify the `line-height` of any element that contains text, and you end up having to repeat yourself in your CSS.

Rather than manually resetting elements, you might want to try using a pre-made CSS reset file.  Eric Meyer's reset (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) is very popular.

Comment: OK so if i have `body {line-height:1}` and later in some elements I don't need `line-height` than i should write specfic CSS for that

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas - Right.  That's the nice part of CSS, how styles cascade until they're overridden.  Elements in the body should inherit the line-height without any extra code.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, or even:

```
*{ line-height:0px; }
```

..to ensure you hit everything. I use Eric Meyer's CSS reset. There's plenty of variations, and I'm sure other SO users have their preferences. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: That's a bit overkill, don't you think?  Is it really that useful?

Comment: I know Meyer Reset he used `body {line-height: 1;}`

Comment: Well, I did a quick edit when I realized I had omitted mention of CSS resets. And, `px` is not necessary on `0`, just force of habit, sorry.